# How to fix Liquibase ValidationFailedExecption in my Spring Boot Project?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

All of my xxx-changeset.xml files runing into a ValidationFailedExecption because of wrong checksum.

I did not changed anything there. The problem comes with an update of liquibase from Version 4.20 to 4.22 the way Liquibase calculate the checksum was changed.

How I can fix it? Is there a way to "update" checksums?

Comment: This issue seems to come due to an updated algorithm in Liquibase 4.22. It seems we may need to downgrade the version in this situation. Please see this [post](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/tag/v4.22.0) and this [post](https://forum.liquibase.org/t/liquibase-4-21-x-introduces-changeset-validation-error/8081/4).

Comment: Thank you verymuch thx to the second post, it leads me to the Information that version 4.23 fixed this issue and is full compatible with <4.21. So to update 4.23 did the trick